# Webkit not responding to my addEventListener click event

Tags: javascript, webkit, element, addeventlistener

I am suspecting that it is the `addEventListener` I have in my code that WebKit does not seem to respond to. This exact same code works fine in Firefox, but again not in Chrome (I know they call it blink).

```
var showSelectedCompany = function() {

    var w = document.getElementById('selection');
    var x = w.selectedIndex;
    var y = w.options[x].value; //options is not the variable name

    var a = document.getElementById('rest01-display');

    a.innerHTML = "Hi, "+y;

    console.log(y);
};
```

This is called in this manner:

```
function _options(value) {

    var resp = JSON.parse(value);

    for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {

        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = resp[i].name;
        option.innerHTML = resp[i].name;
        option.addEventListener("click", showSelectedCompany);

        console.log(option.value);

        create_select.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

This line I think is causing the issue, because I can get the innerHTML from an object in other ways.

**`option.addEventListener("click", showSelectedCompany);`**

**Question**
Could someone please confirm this, and help me out a bit, in how to fix this. I need this to work in all browsers.

**Expectation**
See that the value is put into a `div` and the `console` when an item in the option list is selected.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use a library such as jQuery? Also, can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that jquery will work and may go down that route. But I want to learn native JavaScript a bit better. I will work on the jsfiddle.

Comment: FYI, `node.addEventListener` won't work on IE < 9

Comment: Why are you trying to do a click event on the option elements? You can easily use a single onchange event on the select element itself

Comment: Good point @PatrickEvans. its better to listen to a "change" event on the select element than a "click" on an "option" element.

Comment: I have changed the click into change and that removes the functionality completely

Comment: So the solution for now is that I have added a button that uses the click event. The change event doesn't do anything, but I will look into it more.

Comment: You put the change event on the Select element, not on option element, and it will be triggered once the user selects a different option

Comment: @PatrickEvans Awesome that did it, thought it was weird when the syntax looked right. Was just in the wrong place :-) If you want to earn some extra points, turn it into an answer :-)